# ModuleNotFoundError после запуска созданного .app файла созданного с помощью py2app : No module named 'email_to'

Tags: python, email, app

*Mac M1: VSCode 1.69.2 + Anaconda 2.2.0 - Python 3.9.12 + установлен Python 3.10.5*

Я пытался сделать `*.app` файл который использует библиотеку [email_to](https://pypi.org/project/email-to/), аналог `smtplib + email.mime` ( pip install smtplib + pip install email ) (до этого пробовал их, но там больший объем кода, а ошибка точно такая же).
Если создать `*.app` файл выполняющий отправку письма - то он не работает, хотя сам `*.py` этого проект свою задачу отрабатывает! Возможно нужно что-то дописать в setup.py, но я не знаю что именно, но пробовал, об этом напишу ниже.
Я решил пойти другим путем, и создать вторую `**.py` программу, которую превратил в `**.app` используя библиотеку `py2app`. Содержимое `**.py`:

```
from os import system, getcwd

if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:
        system("git clone https://github.com/syroiezhin/console2app")
        system("python3 carrier.py") # carrier.py == *.py
        system(f"rm -rf {getcwd()}")
    except: pass
```

В результате при запуске `**.app` внутри него создается копия репозитория `*.py`, которую он же сам запускает, и после выполнения - удалит. Но, к сожалению, вылазит одна ошибка, о которой я сказал в начале, которую не получилось решить. Я пробовал:

0. Пробовал в setup.py `install_requires=['email_to']` добавить библиотеки, а так же в OPTIONS перечислить пакеты 'packages': ['email_to']. ожидаемого результата не увидел, ошибка продолжает меня мучать.
1. Пробовал `os.system("pip email_to")` в `*.py`, который будет подгружаться и запускаться, и это тоже не дало результата;
2. Пробовал аналогичный способ с `smtplib + email.mime` аналогичная ошибка, но ругается на эти библиотеки;
3. Пробовал установить через `os.system` - `pip`, чтобы установить эти библиотеки через `os.system`, но он на меня продолжает ругаться, но уже и на `pip`, либо запрашивает пароль в терминале при запуске консольного приложения внутри `**.app`;
4. Пробовал без пакета `email_to` в `*.py` запустить `**.app` файл - работает без ошибок;
5. Пробовал запустить `*.py` файл там где он лежит не запуская `**.app` файл, зайдя внутрь, и он работает без ошибок;
6. Пробовал запускать `**.py` файл не формируя для него `**.app`, и он тоже работает;
7. Когда я запускаю `*.py` файл через запуск `**.app`, в котором записана команда `system("python3 carrier.py")`, то он постоянно пишет одну и ту же ошибку:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email_to'

Проблема возникает либо в подключении библиотек, чтобы `*.py` мог их использовать после копирования репозитория внутрь `**.app` файла. Указывает ошибку в месте вызова `from email_to import Message, EmailServer`. Либо он по разному запускает этот файл `*.py`, в ручную работает, а через `**.app` он не получает доступ к библиотекам установленым на mac. **Какие есть идеи для решения?**

**добавил ещё:**

> Если не устанавливать с репозитория, а заведомо загрузить второй py-файл, а затем там его вызвать, то он выдает такую ошибку, заодно пример setup файла покажу, а формирую файл так:

```
python3 setup.py py2app --packages=PIL,email_to
```

Код setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
APP_NAME = "vrs"
APP = ['agent.py']
DATA_FILES = ['trap4scammers.py']
OPTIONS = {
'includes': ('os', 'PIL', 'email_to'),
'iconfile':'image.jpeg'
}
setup(
name=APP_NAME,
app=APP,
data_files=DATA_FILES,
options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
setup_requires=['py2app']
)
```

[image: при создании app-файла из setup.py приведенного выше - получаем другой тип ошибки]

Answer (score 0):

вопрос с пакетом `email_to` остается открытым.
но мне удалось создать файл приложения без этой ошибки с библиотеками `smtplib + email.mime`!!! работает - вуху.

Я не знаю, что именно могло повлиять из всего, что я сделал, поэтому перечислю, что я сделал:

1. в терминале обновил анаконду которую использую:

```
conda update --force conda
conda update anaconda
conda update conda
```

2. обновил отдельно py2app и примыкающий к нему setuptool:

```
conda uninstall setuptools
conda install setuptools
conda update --force conda
```

3. обновил этот элемент, который иногда меня ругал:

```
conda remove zeromq
conda install zeromq
```

4. Еще добавил вот это, так как оно почему-то перестало работать, иногда использую для проверки скетча:

```
conda install jupyter
```

5. Я также просмотрел [эту статью](https://www.macports.org/install.php).
   Переустановил библиотеки `smtplib + email.mime`, и они внезапно заработали. Пример скачивания:

```
sudo port search email
```